# How to populate one drop down list from another

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reactjs

I have written teh following component to generate two dropdown where the `dllProducts` depends on `ddlCategories` but the issue is when passed the selected product category value to the function() getDataById it wont receive so i removed the code. in the function `ddlPordCatsChanegeEvent()` i have added a comment. Is this the right place to call the function `getDataById()` if not what is the proper way of doing generating the `ddlProducts`

```
var gdata=[];

var trStyle = {
    'color': 'black',
    'border-style' :'solid',
    'margin-left':'20%'
};

var TWODROPDOWNCOMP = React.createClass({
    getInitialState:function(){
    return{data1:[], data2:[], isMounted:false, selectedValue:0}
},
componentDidMount:function(){
    this.getData();
    this.setState({isMounted:true})
},
ddlProdCatsChanegeEvent: function(e) {

    if (this.state.isMounted)
    {
        var newV = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.refProdCats).value;
        var seleValue = newV;

        this.setState({selectedValue:newV}, function(){
            alert(this.state.selectedValue);

            //HOW DO I POPULATE THE OTHER DROPDOWN WITH ID ddlProducts using the child component PRODOPTIONS 
        });

    }
},
render: function() {
    var prodCats = this.state.data1.map(function(ele, index){
        return <PRODCATSOPTION optValue={ele.ProductCategoryID} optText={ele.Name} />
    });

    prodCats.unshift(<PRODCATSOPTION optValue={''} optText={'--- select category ----'} />)

    return (<div>Prodcut Category:<br /><select id="ddlCategories"  ref="refProdCats" onChange={this.ddlProdCatsChanegeEvent}>{prodCats}</select><br />
        Products:<br /><select id="ddlPorducts" ref="refProds"></select><br /></div>
      )
},
getDataById:function(catId){
    var x = catId;
    alert('rec id:'+x);

    $.ajax({
        url:'http://localhost:33401/Home/GetProductCats?id='+ x,
        method:'GET',
        success:function(d1){
            this.setState({data2:d1});
        }.bind(this),
        error:function(){
            alert('ERROR');
        }.bind(this)
    })
},
getData:function(){
    //ajax here
    $.ajax({
        url:'http://localhost:33401/Home/GetProductCats',
        method:'GET',
        success:function(d1){
            this.setState({data1:d1});
        }.bind(this),
        error:function(){
            alert('ERROR');
        }.bind(this)
    })
}
});

var PRODOPTIONS = React.createClass({
    render:function(){
        return(<option value={this.props.optValue}>{this.props.optText}</option> )
    }

});

var PRODCATSOPTION = React.createClass({
    render:function(){
        return(<option value={this.props.optValue}>{this.props.optText}</option> )
    }

});




ReactDOM.render( <TWODROPDOWNCOMP/>,  document.getElementById('d1') );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The select should be populated as you would normally do. After the AJAX call, the options come up.

```
<select id="ddlPorducts" ref="refProds">
  {this.state.data2.map(opt => (
    <option value={opt}>{opt}</option>
  ))}
</select>
```

Comment: but in my situation options also comes as a component. this is a general question when creating a dropdown one would create a parent component for and include the <select> in it then he would create a child component for <option> then from parent he would generate a collection of <option> and place in <select>, is this common way of doing this?

Comment: React is declarative. So, all render happens. What gets shown or hidden in DOM is controlled by state and props.